# Drawing shape over an image using ImageView and matrix

Tags: android, imageview

We are experiencing the following issue for about a week already:
We are drawing an image we want to be able to rescale and "move" on the user's screen.
In order to achieve that, we used an ImageView and a Matrix: it works well.

However, now we're looking for drawing some rectangles over the background image.
These rectangles have to be rescaled and translated along with the background image... The issue we have is that when we create our shape, and paint it using the following code, this is drawn within the top left part of the image, quite like if the whole user's screen was just interpreted as a part of its real dimensions... ?

**My custom ImageView**

```java
public class EnvironmentView extends ImageView {
Matrix matrix;

// We can be in one of these 3 states
static final int NONE = 0;
static final int DRAG = 1;
static final int ZOOM = 2;
int mode = NONE;

// Remember some things for zooming
PointF last = new PointF();
PointF start = new PointF();
float minScale = 1f;
float maxScale = 3f;
float[] m;

int viewWidth, viewHeight;
static final int CLICK = 3;
float saveScale = 1f;
protected float origWidth, origHeight;
int oldMeasuredWidth, oldMeasuredHeight;

public static boolean EDIT_RISKYZONE = false;
static boolean SAVE = false;
ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

Context context;

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Paint paint = new Paint();

    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    paint.setAlpha(80);

    float left = 0;
    float top = 0;
    float right = getWidth();
    float down = getHeight();
    RectF origRect = new RectF(left, top, right, down);

    matrix.mapRect(origRect);
    canvas.drawRect(origRect, paint);



}

public EnvironmentView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    sharedConstructing(context);
}

public EnvironmentView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    sharedConstructing(context);
}

private void sharedConstructing(Context context) {
    super.setClickable(true);
    this.context = context;
    matrix = new Matrix();
    m = new float[9];
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
    setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
}

public void setMaxZoom(float x) {
    maxScale = x;
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    viewWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    viewHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    //
    // Rescales image on rotation
    //
    if (oldMeasuredHeight == viewWidth && oldMeasuredHeight == viewHeight
            || viewWidth == 0 || viewHeight == 0)
        return;
    oldMeasuredHeight = viewHeight;
    oldMeasuredWidth = viewWidth;

    if (saveScale == 1) {
        //Fit to screen.
        float scale;

        Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
        if (drawable == null || drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() == 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() == 0)
            return;
        int bmWidth = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int bmHeight = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

        Log.d("bmSize", "bmWidth: " + bmWidth + " bmHeight : " + bmHeight);

        float scaleX = (float) viewWidth / (float) bmWidth;
        float scaleY = (float) viewHeight / (float) bmHeight;
        scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
        matrix.setScale(scale, scale);

        // Center the image
        float redundantYSpace = (float) viewHeight - (scale * (float) bmHeight);
        float redundantXSpace = (float) viewWidth - (scale * (float) bmWidth);
        redundantYSpace /= (float) 2;
        redundantXSpace /= (float) 2;

        matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);

        origWidth = viewWidth - 2 * redundantXSpace;
        origHeight = viewHeight - 2 * redundantYSpace;
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
    }
}
}
```

**The screen output**

Below is a screenshot of what is shown on the user's screen after he has drawn rectangles in the center of his screen, they are supposed to be about 3/4 of the screen's width and height.

[image]

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Can you replace all the code above with a simple onDraw() method with one imageView, one fixed rectangle and a single matrix that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Possibly the issue is that the image and the rectangles start from a different point, so you may need two matricies with mostly the same operations applied to then but slight difference?

Comment: hmmm... I just did what you said, I updated my post (both the code and the screenshot) so you can see what exactly isn't working as expected (or... ?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image needs to start at the origin (top left -- 0,0).  The rectangle should start half its width from the center of the screen and half its height.

```
int x = (widthOfScreen - widthOfRect)/2;
int y = (heightOfScreen - heightOfRect)/2;
```

So I think you need another matrix.  First translate the second matrix so it would place the rectangle in the center of the screen, then apply the same operations that you do to the other one.  Try doing just this before any other matrix operations are applied (ie comment them all out) and see that it places the rectangle in the right place. Then if is right, it should scale OK.

Comment: It works!! Thank you very much! Right now, I can create my rectangles over the background image and zoom in, zoom out, translate the whole thing... it's awesome :) Thank you, really! I just can't "+1" your answer since I don't have enough reputation... However, one more thing: when I put back the scaling functions in the code, and when I'm working on my scaled environment, I just need to create rectangles "transformed" (means scaled + translated)... I mean: if I am drawing a rectangle after having my environment scaled, they aren't drawn where I expect them to be (right under my finger)...

Comment: Yes, there might be an error in my logic and the translation I described may need to be done at the end, not the beginning, and based on the final size of the rectangle, not the size at the start.  If you can't figure it out cut the whole thing down to just an a bare-minimum onDraw() without any other methods so anyone can just paste it into the onDraw() of their Android app and ask a new question with that.

Comment: hello,as given in answer i took another matrix and translate the another matrix to x and y position. But my rectangle is showing in bottom right side.
//in onDraw 
`newmatrix.setTranslate(x,y)`
`newmatrix.mapRect(origRect)`
Actually I am new in this, please guide me where I am going wrong.

Comment: @Nidhi best to ask a new question explaining what result you want to get in some detail.

Comment: actually I want to get the rectangle draw on center of screen. And as per solution provided by you, I am having some problem in it. Rectangle shifts to bottom right.